# How to insert data in another table by username of logged in and fetch the data from the table in ASP.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I created a restaurant website and created a login table in SQL(Username, Password).
I created a table-booking page in which I take table booking data `(ex: name, email, date, time, table no, additional requests)`.

I want to insert table booking data by the username of the logged-in person and fetch the data by the username.

**Example:** I logged in as *sam123* and I booked a table `(sam, sam@email.com, 23/02/2021, 12:30 pm, table 04, no requests)`. If I log out and log in again I should be able to see my table booking, not anyone else.

How to do it?

Comment: It seems like you haven't tried any solution. Please let us know what specific problem you are facing like, Db connection issue? Insert data problem? etc.. You can get more than handful of tutorial to insert data to sql DB using asp.net. Please specify what your problem exactly is? Where are you finding difficulty ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how or why this is a issue? I mean, how do you pull any thing from the database based on any criteria you are free to use?

so if the user is logged in? Then they say jump to the page with my bookings?

Well, then you just display their tour bookings. the page load event, you pull that data based on their logon name, and simply display the query.

So, you drop in a listview, or a gridview onto that page, and simply pull the data from bookings into that table based on their logon.

So, say you have a gridview control like this in your markup:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Ok, so I dragged a grid view onto my web page.

I have this code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT FirstName, TourName, HotelName, FromDate, ToDate, DestCity from vTours where EmailName = @Email"
    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Tours))

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "kallal@msn.com"
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()

        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

And the results are this:

[image]

Now in above, I hard coded the logon (email), but you would replace the above email condition with your logon.

So, you need/want a query that joins in the user name, and their books. I would save that query as a view, or you can just hand code it out.

That query should have their bookings table and the "user" table as one query.

So, to display their bookings? Just drop in a gridview (1 line of markup!!!!).

Then execute a query and fill a grid view (4 lines of code).